# Flash object makes insecure http request

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, flash

We have a flash object that was made years ago, it makes http request to our server to get data. But since we started using SSL cert. it breaks secure connection when flash object loaded in a page.

I created .htaccess file in the folder that flash object makes request to
I put these in it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But it seems it doesn't work. It still breaks the secure page when flash object is loaded.

Is there any way to solve this problem other than changing swf file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the URL is hard coded (with http://) in the Flash application, there's no way to make it use https by changing anything on the server, you'll need to update the swf.

Any .htaccess rewrites you do will be made after the flash application has already sent the request to the server, and by then you've obviously already sent the insecure request.